# Price alert for specific flight on specific date @ specific time via United?

Tags: price, united-airlines, domestic-travel

I've been monitoring a *very specific nonstop* round-trip ticket from XXX to YYY, leaving on 12/27 @ 08:20AM and returning on 12/30 @ 9:50AM via United. As of right now, this very specific flight is $465/pp.

Is there some type of price alert that will send me an email when this very specific flight drops in price? I went to United and they don't have this particular alert. There's no flexibilty in this flight... it's either this specific flight of nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights) for this. They offer price alerts for specific flights or routes. From their [documentation](https://support.google.com/travel/answer/6235879?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> 1. Go to Google Flights.
> 2. At the top, choose the number of stops, cabin class, and how many tickets you need. Choose your departure airport and destination.
> 3. To track prices for this route, turn on the switch next to "Track prices."
> 4. Optional: To track prices for a specific flight, choose your flights, then click Track price.

This service is worth looking into in general, there are many other very useful features in there.